# IIS Application Initialization call causing 0x80070032 error in event log

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I have set up application initialization requests for my Web API application such that when the application pool recycles certain endpoints are hit in order to load Entity Framework etc into the new process. I can see these requests succeeding in my API log:

> 636603400963248247T16P14184 26/04/2018 11:48:16.324 - Request: GET
>   http://localhost/mywebapi/api/v2/warmup/contact/some-guid-value
>   Host: localhost 
>   User-Agent: IIS Application Initialization Warmup
>   Content-Length: 0
>
> 636603401013021709T8P14184 26/04/2018 11:48:30.297 (8995ms) -
>   Response: 200 GET
>   http://localhost/mywebapi/api/v2/warmup/contact/some-guid-value
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

However, whenever the application pool recycles and these requests are made I get two event log entries as follows:

> Error Message:  An error occurred while communicating with the remote
>   host. The error code is 0x80070032.
>
> Exception Type:  System.Web.HttpException
>
> Exception Source:  System.Web
>
> Stack Trace:     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32
>   result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)    at
>   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()    at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush, Boolean async)    at
>   System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size)    at System.IO.Stream.<>c.b__46_0(Object ) 
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.IO.Stream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.d__15.MoveNext()
>
> Inner Exception:  The request is not supported. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070032)
>
> Exception Type:  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>
> Exception Source:  System.Web
>
> Stack Trace:

The timings of the event log entries seem to coincide with the times of the request and response of the final configured application initialization call.

This occurs when running the website on both a local Windows 10 dev box and Windows 2012 servers.

Does anyone know why these errors are being logged (given that the warmup requests seem to succeed) and how I can avoid them?

Comment: We are getting a similar error in an Azure AppService.  We are an ASP.NET WebAPI app, using EF like you.  I have trace statements at the start of my Warmup method, as well the Controller Constructor.  The log statements never appear -- meaning the Controller never got control.  Did you ever get past this issue?

Comment: Sorry @HowardHoffman I never did get to the bottom of it and we have now moved onto .Net Core. The error did not get logged if I removed the final, third warmup call. This was also the most long-running but I never managed to work out a way of making all three calls without this seemingly spurious error.

Comment: Any clue? Happens to me in win 2019